# Symfony on macOS: brew vs macports

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I recently switched from macports to homebrew. I was running apache and php from macports, which was running smooth and I could work on my Symfony 3.3 development with that setup.

My mac crashed and rebooted, which in fact killed the apache process that was started months ago when I installed it from macports, and it started the one from homebrew instead.

I had to configure a bunch of stuff to make apache/php work again, but now the Symfony app won't work:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 
>   '`Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\LogicException`' with message 'Container extension "*security*" is not registered' in `/path/to/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php` on line 205

I have already cleared the cache (with and without `--no-warmup`), removed everything in `var/{cache,sessions,logs,bootstrap.php.cache}`, ran `composer install` a bunch of times: nothing works.

I don't know what is wrong, because it worked like a charm on my CI server running Debian 9 (I just cloned the repo and ran `composer install`, it worked right away); and it also worked like a charm on my professional host running Debian 8 (same as the CI server).

Comment: If you search for the error message you will see several possible solutions.  This one might help: http://forum.symfony-project.org/forum/32/topic/65023.html

Comment: The solution you mentioned involved a Windows module. Do you want me to dump my php.ini file?

Comment: Not for me.  I have no Mac experience.  I just remember seeing these errors during the Symfony 2.0 to 2.1 transition.  It was generally a composer issue which I assume you have already ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running Debian in a docker container.
I'm much more comfortable with Linux for servers anyways.

I'd still want an answer, because in the end I only avoided the error ;)